# Gridx/Dojo & jQuery : Is there a callback when sorting is completed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo, node-webkit, dojo.gridx

[image]

This table is generated using GridX / dojo in NodeWebkit. The "[BV][B][V]" are links that are handled by jQuery using class selector. However, once I sort the grid, the listeners are unbinded. How do I reapply the click function? Is there a callback when sorting & rendering is complete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no callback or event that I know of when sorting is complete in gridx.

However, the whole grid is re-rendered when it is sorted or filtered. So you can use something like:

```
grid.connect(grid.body, 'onRender', function(){
    $(document).on("click", "a.myBVlink", function() {
      ...
    });
    $(document).on("click", "a.myBlink", function() {
      ...
    });
    $(document).on("click", "a.myVlink", function() {
      ...
    });
});
```

Comment: This works. But renders twice - not a problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I created a wrapper div and added the click listener to it as -

```
$('#gridWrapper').on('click','.myLinkClass',function(){
    console.log('clicked');
    console.log(this);
});
```

`gridWrapper` is not changed. So the listener remains active and the `.myLinkClass` selector selects the `<a href="#" class="myLinkClass">text</a>` in spite of sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Like @mccannf initiated I use the re-rendering event. For preventing double working I just use a counting variable and do the work only the second time.
**Note:** If at initial the grid is empty than I set the counter to 1 because than the event is only called once.

```
var countRender = 0;
if (grid.store.data.length == 0) countRender=1; 

grid.connect(grid.body, 'onRender', function(gridName){
    if (!countRender++) return;
    countRender=0;
    ...
});
```